# How to pass parameter into internal function

Tags: javascript

I did not manage to pass i as parameter from onready() into setInterval(), so meanwhile I parsed the loop:

```
function myFunc() {
  myWidgets[0].onready = function(){
    setInterval( function(){
      var pVal = $('#Pv1').text();
      myWidgets[0].setValue(pVal);
    }, 1000);
  };

  myWidgets[1].onready = function(){
    setInterval( function(){
      var pVal = $('#Pv2').text();
      myWidgets[1].setValue(pVal);
    }, 1000);
  };

  myWidgets[2].onready = function(){
    setInterval( function(){
      var pVal = $('#Pv3').text();
      myWidgets[2].setValue(pVal);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

How can I add i as parameter?

the following did not work , i is undefined in the internal function in setInterval:

```
  myWidgets[i].onready = function(i){
    setInterval( function(i){
      var j = i + 1;
      var pVal = $('#Pv' + j).text();
      myWidgets[i].setValue(pVal);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Comment: Did you run it in a loop, or like you posted? Make `$('#Pv' + j).text();` using `j.toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use enclosure to make the current value of `i` accessible throught `onready`:

```
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    (function(x){
        myWidgets[x].onready = function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                var pVal = $('#Pv' + (x+1) ).text();
                myWidgets[x].setValue(pVal);
            }, 1000);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Without an enclosure, the reason why it fails to use the current value of `i` is that it won't use the value at the current step of the loop. Rather than that, it will use the value of `i` *when `onready` occurs*, which is already maxed as the loop is over.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a function enclosure.

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    myWidgets[i].onready = function() {
      setInterval(function(){
         var pVal = $('#Pv'+(i+1)).text();
         myWidgets[i].setValue(pVal);
      }, 1000);
    };
  })(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this. The case you are referring to is closure

myWidgets = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myWidgets[i].onready = (function(i){
        return function(){setInterval( function(){
            var pVal = $('#Pv' + (i+1) ).text();
            myWidgets[i].setValue(pVal);
            console.log(i)
        }, 1000);}
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, but i dont know if it is the answer on your question.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
myWidgets[i].onready = function(){
     setInterval( function(){
        var pVal = $('#Pv' + (i+1) ).text();
        myWidgets[i].setValue(pVal);
     }, 1000);
};
}
```

It has everything to do with scopes and callback. Your solution does not work because the callback function of onReady does not know the context, for example does not know the `i`.

You can make this better with jQuery. (each widget has a class myWidget)

```
$('.myWidget').ready(function () {
    var element = $(this); // is the widget of your code. 
    setTimeout(function () { element.val(element.val()*1 + 1); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation of the APIs you are trying to use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval
will tell you this:

**Syntax**

```
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

Borrowing code from the answer by @Haneev it can be written as follows.

I am using `j` as formal parameter to make it obvious it is not using `i` from the outer scope.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myWidgets[i].onready = function(){
         setInterval( function(j){
            var pVal = $('#Pv' + (j+1) ).text();
            myWidgets[j].setValue(pVal);
         }, 1000, i);
    };
    }
```